# Docker - Selenium Hub

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-docker

I'm using a Docker image for Selenium (selenium/standalone-chrome).
My goal is to use it for integration testing with some python scripts.
Everything works pretty fine, I'm using the driver with remote:

```
browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://192.168.99.100:4444/wd/hub',   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

My goal is to create a Chrome profile that will be persistend on the docker image, and I can reuse it in the scripts with a command like:

```
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

How can I create the persisten profile?
Thx

Comment: You will have to create the profile in the image, and then bake it in. See `docker commit` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: I'm unable to find any documentation driving me in that direction: how can i run creating a specific profile?